# Expectation value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've been thinking about problem that, conceptually is very simple. I have two random variables $F_{x}$ and $F_{y}$ both of which follow a Gaussian distribution of mean $0$ and variance $1$. Now, I wish to compute the expectation value, $\langle\sqrt{F_{x}^2 + F_{y}^2}\rangle$. It's been more than a while since I did any probability theory and am wondering if there is an easy way of doing this. I keep on running into nasty integrals, but I may be approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration is not bad. Change to **polar** coordinates. One integration by parts, and we are at an integral that is familiar. We don't even need to integrate by parts, since the integral with respect to $r$ can be found from the variance.

Comment: Hi Andre, could you elaborate a bit more on how to find the probability density function for $\sqrt{F_{x}^2 + F_{y}^2}$?

Comment: One could find the pdf. But we don't need to. The expectation is the double integral of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ times the joint density function, which is $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$. Now change to polar coordinates.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The problem is trivial now. Just out of curiosity, how would you go about finding the pdf?

Comment: Let $W$ be our square root. We want the cdf of $W$, that is, $\Pr(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\le w)$. This is the double integral of the joint density over the circle centre the origin, radius $w$. To evaluate the double integral, change to polar coordinates. The $r \,dr\,d\theta$ gives us an integral that is easy by substitution $u=r^2/2$. So now we have the cdf, differentiate for the density.